# Eclipse 2022-3 no longer support CVS?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, cvs

[image]

After upgrading Eclipse to the latest version, 2022-3, I found it seems 'Eclipse CVS Client' plug-in is no longer available in the official software source, which has been the way to install the CVS support for the past several versions. Any idea how to install CVS support going forward?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I extracted the original Eclipse CVS Client plugin from the now empty [eclipse.platform.team](https://github.com/eclipse-platform/eclipse.platform.team) repository. The Eclipse maintenance team stopped maintaining the plugin and removed it from the Eclipse code base in 2022. The rest of the Eclipse Team sources were moved to [Eclipse core](https://github.com/eclipse-platform/eclipse.platform).

[My git repository](https://github.com/JAndrassy/org.eclipse.team.cvs) is a copy of the eclipse.platform.team repository so it preserves the commits history of the plugins sources.

Eclipse CVS plugin for Eclipse 2023 versions update site URL: https://storage.googleapis.com/eclipse-cvs-plugin/

Comment: Good work! Unfortunately, there is no Eclipse maintenance team. You would have been and are welcome to contribute it. Whatever, it's good to have you as the new (unofficial) Eclipse maintenance team for CVS! ;) Consider to add it to the [Eclipse Marketplace](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/) (click the [_Add Content_](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/addcontent) link) for better visibility. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for that fix! I recently installed the plugin into Eclipse 2023-06 and it 's working great. I appreciate your note in GitHub regarding how the repo looks empty, so I'll pass the info from you along here: If the repo looks empty after you enter the url into the "Install New Software..." dialog - uncheck "Group Items by Category" in that dialog.

Answer (score 9):

**Update:** For recent Eclipse versions see [Juraj's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76826924/6505250).

Yes, as [announced in September 19, 2021](https://www.eclipse.org/lists/cross-project-issues-dev/msg18643.html), Eclipse 2021-12 (4.22) was the last release containing CVS support.

Installing the *Eclipse CVS Client* from the Eclipse 4.22 update site [`https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.22`](https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.22) might work. Otherwise, you have to build it yourself.

Consider to [subscribe to the Eclipse *cross-project-issues-dev* mailing list](https://accounts.eclipse.org/mailing-list/cross-project-issues-dev) to not to miss such things.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the CVS plugin.
CVS is still very useful for versioning of scripts.
It still works after in-place upgrade to Eclipse 2022-03.
Hope this will be the case with future Eclipse versions.

Comment: Looks like older CVS support won't work any more: https://github.com/eclipse-platform/eclipse.platform.team/issues/29